# Split TraceSource to Multiple Levels of TraceListeners

Tags: .net, app-config, trace

I trying to setup MySource trace source using two different log levels. FileLog should trace everything (verbose) and system event log should trace only Errors.

The following setup appears to have killed logging to FileLog. What am I doing wrong?

```
<sources>
  <source name="MySource" switchName="MySource.Switch">
    <listeners>
      <add name="FileLog"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="MySource" switchName="MySource.SystemSwitch">
    <listeners>
      <add name="EventLog"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<switches>
  <add name="MySource.Switch" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="MySource.SystemSwitch" value=Error"/>
</switches>
```

Answer (score 6):

You include `<source>` only one per source, with multiple listeners, then add filters on listeners, like so:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="Service" switchValue="Information">
        <listeners>
          <clear />
          <add name="RollingFile" />
          <add name="EventLog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="RollingFile"
        type="Essential.Diagnostics.RollingFileTraceListener, Essential.Diagnostics"
        initializeData="{ApplicationName}-{DateTime:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        template="{LocalDateTime:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} {Message}{Data}"
      />
      <add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="YourAppName">
        <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Warning" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```